# Where is Buddha Now?

Tags: doubt

Namaste to Buddha. How and where is Buddha now? Does he still teaching now?

I am trying to understand Nibbana and where Buddha is now.

What I understand is that Nibbana is a state rather than a location or place. This state has no physical body, no desire, no dukkha and no more incarnation.

Many have mentioned this state appears as in empty space but I would think the "empty" is a meaning of Buddhism that is 100% free from dukkha .

> Endless space is called in Atthasālini ajatākāsa, 'unentangled', i.e.
> unobstructed or empty space.

[Why don't we realise space instead of Nibbana?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/22540/why-dont-we-realise-space-instead-of-nibbana)

In Quantum Physics, a state is a source of energy so it's quantifiable and appears as a particle wave. An energy cannot be null or void state too as the law of conservation of energy states that energy can neither be created nor destroyed - only converted from one form of energy to another. [Wave–particle duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality)

Conclusion is can I say that Buddha is still teaching and around, appears as the supreme particle wave and possibly can be communicated via meditation? Any form of energy can be interfered/communicated/entangled with based on Physic theory ?

> The universe encompasses everything that exists, according to our
> current understanding: spacetime, forms of energy and the physical
> laws that relate them, history, philosophy, mathematics and logic.
> Buddhists refer to the Universe, both visible and invisible phenomena,
> as the Dharma.
> [The Origin of Meditation: Making Bonds with the Universe](https://www.meditationmag.com/buddhism/origin-meditation-making-bonds-universe)

Anyone could verify my understanding above?

Comment: @chrisw can I ask another question. topic change to "Nibbana in Quantum Physic" but content almost same

Comment: or change the ques title - "Where is Buddha now based on Quantum Physic"

Comment: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/39740/can-you-explain-how-cessation-of-existence-is-known-to-be-possible maybe this

Comment: I studied "Applied Mathematics" (of Quantum Physics) at university, and what I was I taught there seems to me completely unrelated to Buddhism. I wouldn't describe the Buddha as a (physical) "wave" nor as a "particle" -- see also [quantum woo](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Quantum_woo) and so on, and this physicist's phrase [Not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong). For what it's worth there are a dozen [Questions containing "quantum"](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=quantum+is%3Aquestion) on this site.

Comment: @ChrisW There are many research that Physics and Buddhism is related ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_and_science.  will check on the links that u provided. thanks Chris

Comment: @Letsbuddhism ya it's related to this ques. thanks